# Adding custom class in Slick slider like increment in number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, slick.js

How to add a custom class in slick slider like following structure

```
<div class="slick-slide">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-slide1">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-slide2">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-slide3">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-slide4">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide slick-active slick-slide5">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide">...</div>
<div class="slick-slide">...</div>
```

I Need to add class only to the active slider(".slick-active"). And need to change the class on changing the slide.

I am using the following code, but it doesn't working.

```
$(".slider").slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows : true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 500
});

$('.slider').on({beforeChange: function (event, slick, current_slide_index, next_slide_index) {
   $('.slick-slide').removeClass('slick-main-active');
   $('.slick-slide[data-index=' + next_slide_index + ']').addClass('slick-main-active');
}})
```

> Note: I refer this code from another site. May be this is wrong, i
>   just showing what i did.

[image]

Comment: Just FYI if you're wanting to select the current slide you can use the in-built class of `slick-current`.

Comment: No i don't want to select current slide. I just want to add class name with count (1,2,3,4,5) to the current silde.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the `data-slick-index` attribute, or even something like `.slick-active:nth-child(1)` for your selectors? It seems like we're trying to re-invent the wheel here.

Comment: Yeah i tried with .slick-active:nth-child(1) .slick-active:nth-child(2) .slick-active:nth-child(3) it dose not working. But the  .slick-active:nth-child(odd) .slick-active:nth-child(even) Will work.

Comment: What about using the attribute selector `.slider [data-slick-index="1"]`?

Comment: I have attached a screen shot above there i have a 5 current .slick-active, but there is 12 [data-slick-index].

Comment: Ok, I think I get what you're saying now - I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a custom selector for each of the current X active slides, this should do it ([CodePen here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZMGEX)):

```
$("#test").on("init", function(event, slick) {
    addCustomSlickAttributes();
})

$("#test").slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows : true,
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 500
})

$("#test").on("afterChange", function(event, slick, current_slide_index, next_slide_index) {
    addCustomSlickAttributes();
})

function addCustomSlickAttributes() {
    // Remove old attributes
    $("[data-my-slick-attr]").removeAttr("data-my-slick-attr");

    // Iterate through each active slide and add our custom attribute
    $(".slick-active").each(function(index, el) {
        $(el).attr("data-my-slick-attr", index);
    })
}
```

You can then target the active elements with `[data-my-slick-attr="0"]`, `[data-my-slick-attr="1"]`, etc.

Comment: Thank you chief, It is exactly what i want.